# Scala return types with foreach and map

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, and I'm getting confused on how functions stitch together and their return types. Consider the following:

```
val nodes = List(0,1,2)               
val links = List(List(1, 2), List(1, 0), List(1,3))
```

Each node has a bi-directional link, as described in the tuple-pair 'links'. I am attempting to building a map where each node points to it's neighbours, for example

```
Map(0 -> List(1), 1 -> List(2, 0), 2 -> List(1) )
```

However, my initial thinking on how to code this has me stumped on why it's returning an empty 'List[Any]' value.

```
nodes.foreach(z => (links.map { case List(a,b) => if(a == z) a else if (b == z) b }))
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Why doesn't `1 -> List(0, 2, 3)`?  Isn't `3` a neighbor? And why isn't `3 -> List(1)` in there?

Comment: Notation for pairs is `val links = List(1 -> 2, 1 -> 0)` or parens `(1,2)` etc.

Comment: Yeah, as @som-snytt said, you should probably use `Tuple2` instead of `List` for pairs as we know that pair always contains 2 items. In scala, to create a Tuple2 you can use any of `Tuple2(a, b)`, `(a, b)`, or `a -> b`.

Comment: @jwvh, you're correct and it should be 1->List(2,0,3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or,

```
scala> nodes.map(n => (n, links.flatMap {
     | case List(`n`, x) => Some(x)
     | case List(x, `n`) => Some(x)
     | case _ => None }))
res3: List[(Int, List[Int])] = List((0,List(1)), (1,List(2, 0, 3)), (2,List(1)))
```

As commented,

```
scala> .toMap
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(0 -> List(1), 1 -> List(2, 0, 3), 2 -> List(1))
```

Comment: You probably should call `toMap` at the end as the user wants to get a map.

Comment: @Darkhan yes, I only intended to comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code:

First of all, `foreach` returns `Unit` as you can see in the [Scala Doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@foreach(f:A=%3EUnit):Unit)

Also, your condition is not entirely correct - e.g. for node `0` and connection `1<->0` you are going to print `0` but you actually want to return `1`.

---

The correct code would go like this:

```
val nodes = List(0,1,2)               
val links = List(List(1, 2), List(1, 0), List(1,3))
val result = nodes.map(z => 
    (z, links.flatMap { 
                case List(a,b) => if(a == z && nodes.contains(b)) Some(b) else if (b == z && nodes.contains(a)) Some(a) else None 
              }
    )
).toMap
println(result)
```

Notice how I am calling `map` on the `nodes` list (instead of `foreach`) - this gives me then the possibility to call `toMap` at the end - which is returning a Map (what you want to achieve eventually). Also I am **map**ping each node to a `Pair` of the node and a List of its neighbours

**Note 2:** I added a condition which checks if the discovered neighbour is part of the nodes collections (with `contains`) - as this is how your example is. If you have a different requirement, just remove it

Will give:

```
Map(0 -> List(1), 1 -> List(2, 0), 2 -> List(1))
```

Comment: I do not think the result should contain `Unit` type. You can use Option inside `if` and and then call `flatten` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure where you get a `List[Any]` in your code example.

However, `foreach` takes a function with return type `Unit`as argument and therefore returns `Unit`. It is basically a classic *for each loop* for side effects.

The 'map' function of the `List` *collection* can turn a `List[A]` into a `List[B]`. So if your were for example to return either a `List[Int]` or an `Int` in your `map` function, the *smallest* common ancestor type of both would `Any` so the result would be a `List[Any]`.

However, as scala has a very powerful collections API, there is an easy solution.

Explicitly, you can provide a `CanBuildFrom[List[Int], List[Int], Map[Int, Int]]` to build a `Map[Int, List[Int]]` from a `List[Int]` while *mapping* using a function `Int => (Int, Int)`

*But* scala provides an even easier way to accomplish that (Have a look at [breakOut](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/#scala.collection.package)).

So, if I interpreted your question correctly, you would need something like this:

```
val neighbors: Map[Int, List[Int]] = nodes.map(z =>
  z -> links.withFilter(_.contains(z)).flatMap(_.filter(candidate => candidate != z && nodes.contains(candidate)))
)(collection.breakOut)

--> neighbors: Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(0 -> List(1), 1 -> List(2, 0), 2 -> List(1))
```